# Homestead on windows, not accessible trough browser

Tags: windows, ssh, vagrant, homestead

I'm trying to set up a homestead machine on my Windows8 PC, for Laravel development. I have managed to get the machine up and running, I can SSH into it. 
But somehow visiting http://homestead.app doesn't work. 
I returns "This web page is not available".

I added this line to my hosts file:

```
  192.168.10.10  homestead.app
```

My Gitbash did say at a certain piont: "Warning: Connection timeout. Retrying..." But continued anyway.

This is how my Homestead.yaml looks like:

```
---
ip: "192.168.10.10"
memory: 2048
cpus: 1
provider: virtualbox

authorize: ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub

keys:
    - ~/.ssh/id_rsa

folders:
    - map: ~/Code
      to: /home/vagrant/Code

sites:
    - map: homestead.app
      to: /home/vagrant/Code/Laravel/public

databases:
    - homestead

variables:
    - key: APP_ENV
      value: local

# blackfire:
#     - id: foo
#       token: bar
#       client-id: foo
#       client-token: bar

# ports:
#     - send: 93000
#       to: 9300
#     - send: 7777
#       to: 777
#       protocol: udp
```

Comment: In the end I was so annoyed, I decided to install a dual boot with Ubuntu on my pc, now running Homestead from Ubuntu, works like a charm, not had a problem once getting Homestead up and running. With Windows every time I shut the pc down and restarted, problems started over again.

Answer (score 0):

You can redirect your request to your host port and with your host machine you would be able to access you app.